# If, elseif and else conditionals in the preamble

Tags: conditionals, preamble

I have a scenario where I need to define a few commands and environments based on some condition in the preamble. I used to use `\newtoggle`, set the conditional using `\toggletrue` or `\togglefalse` and use `\iftoggle` macros defined in the `etoolbox` package. However, the conditionals that I have now are not bound by the boolean type. It conforms to the below if-else structure

```
if <condition 1>
    define commands <a1, a2>
    define environments <b1, b2>
elseif <condition 2>
    define commands <a3, a4>
    define environments <b3, b4>
.. 
else
    define commands <p, q>
    define environments <x, y>
```

I tried using the `algorithmic` package, but apparently, I cannot make use of that in the preamble. Is there any way I could define multi-conditional if-else cases in the preamble?.

`Update 1` The command and environment names in the different cases will be the same, just the definition will be different

`Update 2` The conditions are multiple `toggles`. I plan to use the `\newtoggle` commands to define the conditional variables.

```
\newtoggle{variable1}
\toggletrue{variable1}
\newtoggle{variable2}
\togglefalse{variable2}
```

The pseudo code for the conditionals are as follows

```
% The conditions
if variable1 && variable2
    % do something
else if variable1 && !variable2
    % do something else
else if !variable1 && variable2
    % do the thing
else 
    % do the other thing
```

I know this can be done using nested if-conditionals, but I was wondering if there are any non-nested ways to do it.

Comment: Do you mean the `\if...\else...\fi` syntax? For numeric (i.e. integer numbers conditions) there is `\ifcase` ...

Comment: Can you explain the conditions? That is, what are `<condition 1>`, `<condition 2>`, ...?

Comment: @Werner Updated the question

Comment: please see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf#page=141

Comment: @Rakesh: As far as I know, you can't use toggles together in a row with `&&` etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As in almost any programming language, `\if...` statements can be nested, however, there's no `\elseif`, so `\else \if....` has to be used and concluded with `\fi`.

A new `\if...` variable (well, macro actually) can be defined with

`\newif\ifsomename`

which is initially set to the false state. `\somenametrue` will set to `true`, `\somenamefalse` will set it false.

Nested `\if...\fi` can be very tedious, in TeX, however.

Here's some pseudo-code

```
\ifsomething...
 do this and that
\else
\ifsomethingother
...
\else
\ifsomethingmore
\fi
\fi
\fi
```

The following small example should print 'Foo that' with bold font, since `\dothattrue` was specified.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newif\ifdothis

\newif\ifdothat

\dothattrue  % Setting the state of the boolean variable \ifdothat` to true, otherwise it's false already (or use \dothatfalse explicitly)

\ifdothis

\newcommand{\foo}{\textbf{Foo}}
\else
\ifdothat
\newcommand{\foo}{\textbf{Foo that}}
\else
\newcommand{\foo}{\textbf{Dummy content}}
\fi % \fi of \ifdothat
\fi % Outer \fi


\begin{document}
\foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: This functionality is what I was looking for. However, I guess there is no escaping nested conditionals in case of multiple cases.

Comment: @Rakesh: No, not with `\if...` and `toggles` from `etoolbox`. You could use `\AND` etc. operators with `xifthen` boolean variables

Answer (score 7):

Multiple conditions can be handled with plain TeX conditionals using `\ifnum`, for example

```
\ifnum0%
  \iffirstsomething 1\fi
  \ifsecondsomething 1\fi
  >0 %
  % Do stuff
\fi
```

which will only do the stuff if at least one condition is met. Similarly

```
\ifnum0%
  \iffirstsomething\else1\fi
  \ifsecondsomething\else1\fi
  =0 %
  % Do stuff
\fi
```

will be true only if both conditions are met.

Comment: This is a nice way to do it as well!